# Problems implementing an easy REST service - Spring MVC

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a Springboot application (a videoclub application). I do not think it is necessary to show you all the code as it would be very verbose. But it works fine.

A class `Film`, and `FilmRepository` with some methods, a controller, database JPA, and the HTML files. Everything works fine. **I am not looking for a code solution, but more for a "conceptual" solution**, just to know if I am implementing properly the REST service.

I want to add now a really easy REST service (adding a class "MyRestController") that will search for a film just by adding the name of it in the URL.

So apart from my Controller, I want to add this RestController just to do this simple thing: If I add the name of a film in the URL, it will search for it with the normal MVC methods.

But adding what I think is the solution gives me this error:

> There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
>   No message available

So when going through the HTML content to the page to search for the film, and adding to that `/buscar` the film name (which I have in the db) `/buscar/Interstellar`, it shows the before error.

```
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
public class MyRestController {

    @Autowired
    private FilmRepository filmRepo;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/buscar", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<Film>> getFilms(@RequestParam String Title) {
        List<Film> pelis = (List<Film>) filmRepo.findByTitle(Title);
        HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.OK;
        ResponseEntity<List<Film>> response = new ResponseEntity<>(pelis, status);
        return response;
    }
}
```

Getting this error makes me think the page knows it has to do something, but might be having trouble getting it (due to strings, iterable things, lists, or that sort of problem, JSON maybe). But I do not know if the "theory" behind the rest service is alright in MyRestController.

Film repository:

```
public interface FilmRepository extends CrudRepository<Film, Long>{

    Iterable<Film> findByTitle(String Title);
}
```

(The MVC method in the normal controller)

```
@RequestMapping("/buscar")
    public ModelAndView processSearch(@RequestParam(value = "title", required = false) String title) {
        if (title == null || title == "") {
            Iterable<Film> films = filmRepo.findAll();
            return new ModelAndView("buscar").addObject("films", films);
        }
        Iterable<Film> films = filmRepo.findByTitle(title);
        return new ModelAndView("buscar").addObject("films", films);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the problem was with the @RequestParam, which makes you search in the URL with a query like: /buscar?Title=Interstellar

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/buscar/{title}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<Film>> getFilms(@PathVariable String title) {
    List<Film> pelis = (List<Film>) filmRepo.findByTitle(title);
    HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.OK;
    ResponseEntity<List<Film>> response = new ResponseEntity<>(pelis, status);
    return response;
}
```

With this REST service, you can search by URL like "/buscar/Interstellar".

The result is going to give you JSON content with all the information of the Object Film.

Answer (score 0):

What you're talking about is a `@PathVariable`

```
@RequestMapping(path={"/buscar","/buscar/{title}"})
public ModelAndView processSearch(@PathVariable(value = "title", required=false) String title) {
```

Comment: That does indeed work only if specified a title. If not, it gives a POST error. 

How ever, that does not work as a rest service, but as a MVC (model, view, controller). I am looking to do what you are saying, BUT ALSO WITH a rest, so you can do both, with the MVC and with the rest if specified by the url (ResponseEntity).

Comment: Edited answer, you could add multiple path mapping

Comment: Yes, AND it works but not as a REST CONTROLLER! Forget the ModelAndView! I wrote it so you could see the method existed somewhere! I am looking for what I am doing wrong in the MyRestController

Comment: the way you declared in `MyRestController`, it except something like `/buscar?title=someTitle` as you used @RequestParam, but it's not what you asked in your question `that will search for a film just by adding the name of it in the url.`